# When I refresh tokent by using BackgroundFetch of expo, the token is not refreshed

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

When I refresh tokent by using BackgroundFetch of expo, the token is not refreshed.

How can I refresh user token to use refresh api in background of app?

Here is my code:

```
const refreshToken = async () => {
   await LoginApis.refresh()
};

const registerTokenRefreshTask = async () => {
TaskManager.defineTask(REFRESH_TASK_NAME, refreshToken);
const isTaskRegistered = await TaskManager.isTaskRegisteredAsync(REFRESH_TASK_NAME);
console.log(isTaskRegistered)

if (!isTaskRegistered) {
    // Schedule the task to run every 30 minutes
    await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(REFRESH_TASK_NAME, {
        minimumInterval: REFRESH_INTERVAL,
        stopOnTerminate: false,
        startOnBoot: true,
    });
}
};

export default function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
        registerTokenRefreshTask()
    }, []);
...
```